# How To Change browser font in Chrome For Android?

Tags: chrome-for-android, fonts

I am a seasoned Linux developer, tinkering with Android.

I want to modify Chrome so that it uses the font I want as default.

So far I've found

```
/data/data/com.android.chrome/shared_prefs/com.android.chrome_preferences.xml
```

But it seems to sync settings from Google cloud?

Anyone know markup to specify font?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [Per App fonts](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.zst.xposed.perappfonts) -an Xposed module. It requires root though